# Como abrir un archivo de Excel con Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Tengo el siguiente problema y no se que me falta en el código. Necesito que cuando ejecute el código me abra en dataFrame que he construido y guardado en el código

tengo el siguiente código y las dos opciones que he intentado

```
import pandas as pd
import os

ejemplo = ('C:/Users/adatos/Desktop/AUTOMATIZACION/AUTOMATIZACION PARAMETRIZACION INVENTARIO/EJEMPLO.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(ejemplo, header=0)

#Creando columna
df['NUMERO'] = 0

df.to_excel('pruebaEjemplo.xlsx')

os.system("open -a 'path/Microsoft Excel.app''C:/Users/adatos/pruebaEjemplo.xlsx'")

#os.system(ejemplo)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que quiero obtener es que cuando ejecute el código automáticamente abra el archivo de Excel asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomendo investigar como abrir archivos con los programas predeterminados independientemente de la plataforma (o según la plataforma que uses). Pues aparentemente, open no existe en cmd. Si pruebas el mismo comando en cmd y no funciona (lo cual es casi seguro), entonces el problema está en el comando, no en python.

Comment: Si solo te importa que funcione bien en Windows, usa [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Comment: Amigo gracias, con os.startfile me funciono